# Spring internationalization on home page

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to implement spring mvc internationalization on my login and Home screen(page comes up after successful login) page.
I tried to do this on login page and its working successfully by using the following code,

```
webui-servlet.xml


    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:ValidationMessages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
         <property name="cookieName" value="clientlanguage"/>
         <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="31449600"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">

    </bean>

    <bean id="defaultViews" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
            <property name="prefixJson" value="true"/>
        </bean>

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" ></bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:interceptors>  
        <bean class="com.check.util.RequestInterceptor"/> 

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
              <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>



login.jsp

        <a href="?lang=en" >
            <img src="/images/language_flags/en.jpg" class="seltdLanHeight" alt="en" />
        </a>    

web.xml

<display-name>WebUI</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webui</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoadProperty</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.check.servlet.LoadProperty</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webui</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/webui-servlet.xml,
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

but when I use the same on home screen page, then language changed but it redirects to login page again.

Please let me know is there any solution that keeps me to stay on the same page from where am changing the language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Strange, that should not happen in my opinion. There is probably something "smelly" going on. You should try to find out which component is making the redirect. First suspect would be security filter chain (possibly `ExceptionTranslationFilter`).

Comment: how to check "ExceptionTranslationFilter",can you please tell me in detail..Am new to this..should i put any filter check on web.xml file..

Comment: If you know how to debug your application, then put a breakpoint in there. Or you might put breakpoint directly inside `Response#sendRedirect(...)`. If you don't know how to debug your application, there might be other ways - e.g. disable security (allow anonymous access) and check if the redirects still happen.

Comment: Or maybe as a first step just enable DEBUG level logging and check what is going on inside Spring.

Comment: can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please let me know is there any solution.

Comment: And what about the debugging or logging I suggested? Have you tried it?

Comment: @pavel Horal .Thanks for the replay..Yeah i did,but i couldn't track the issue using that.

Comment: Can you share log with the DEBUG messages (e.g. via http://pastebin.com/)?